# Applying bottom Soldermask layer to EAGLE board

Tags: pcb-design, eaglecad, pcb-layers, solder-mask

everyone. I have a problem with one of my designed boards. I submitted my order to PCBWay for checking my files before ordering and I was informed that there is **no bottom Soldermask layer**. This confused me since I have not encountered any layer named as such in the EAGLE layers list. Maybe this is a layer that exists in that list? I have browsed online and found that the areas on tStop and bStop are where the solder mask is not applied. Since I do not have any components or pads in the bottom only a few traces as I used vias, how do I enable or incorporate this layer into my design?

Some of the suggestions that PCBWay was kind enough to give are:

1. Cover with the solder mask ink all
2. Do solder mask opening all
3. Or you can add the layer and resubmit the file.

I am not sure how to do this task related to the solder mask. If you have anything to share a link to a tutorial or video (I tried finding to no avail), please do share. I thank you for taking your time to read, looking forward to learning from everyone.

Answer (score 1):

They mean bStop. The layer is missing because it is empty: no pads on the bottom layer means no openings in the soldermask.

The answer is (1): you want the whole bottom side covered in soldermask.

Comment: Thank you. I have discussed the same thing and they've confirmed that the bottom side will be completely covered in soldermask.